# Different callbacks for error or error as first argument?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

We (and the JS SO chat room) had a talk with @rlemon some days ago about his [Little-XHR](https://github.com/rlemon/Little-XHR) library about error handling.

Basically, we wanted to decide which error handling pattern should be used:

```
xhr.get({
    // Some parameters, and then
    success: function(data) {},
    failure: function(data) {}
})
```

Or:

```
xhr.get({
    // Some parameters, and then
    callback: function(err, data) {}
})
```

One is more jQuery-like, while the other is more Node-like. Some say that the first pattern makes you think more about handling error. I think the opposite, since you may forget the other callback function, while the argument is always there on the second pattern.

Any opinion/advantage/drawback about both these patterns?

Comment: `xhr.get({ ... }, function (err, data) {})` At least get the pattern right

Answer (score 5):

The real important feature is style consistency so you can write code in the same style and you can make meta programming assumptions about how asynchronous situations are handled.

I personally prefer

`(err, data)` because it's a standard way of handling things. It allows for function composition.

For example [`after.map`](https://github.com/Raynos/after.js#after.map) uses this pattern. So code like

```
after.map(["foo.js", "bar.js"], function (fileName, callback) {
    fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, file) {
        callback(err, file)
    })
}, function (err, files) {
    // handle files
})
```

can be simplified to

```
after.map(["foo.js", "bar.js", fs.readFile, function (err, files) {
    // handle files
})
```

Another advantage is that you can pass in a callback as a last parameter

```
asyncOperation(options, function (err, data) {
    // not nested inside an object literal
})
```

The callback last approach is a nice API familiarity approach.

A further advantage is that you can easily forget to set the `error` handler in your object literal, or set it to some kind of default error handler.

When your using `(err, data)` it reminds you to think about how to efficiently handle this err every time.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I like to remember that **explicit is always better than implicit.**

Using this, I'd typically side with explicit `success` and `failure` functions - you know exactly what you're dealing with the moment you open that code up - success deals calls that finished successfully, while error deals with calls that had a problem.

The alternative, using a single method, will take longer to read when you go to modify that code. Besides, you'd likely end up with something like this;

```
xhr.get({
    callback: function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // handle that error somehow
        }
        else {
            // deal with success somehow
        }
    }
})
```

And that kind of boilerplate gets boring, fast.

Not to mention, if you forget to add this boilerplate, and for example, you're only handling success, then a new developer entering the code base may not see see a problem with it. But having explicit error/success callbacks, they'd be able to see pretty quickly that you're missing an `error` callback and start working on a way to handle it, or at least figure out "well, this is only handling success - I must find a way to handle errors". It makes the code seem less magical.

Comment: its harder to see your missing an error callback and easier to see your not handling the first `err` parameter

Answer (score 2):

**Separate callbacks**

If the `xhr.get()` call succeeds, then `err` is redundant. If the call fails. `data` is redundant. Rather than forcing client code to check the state of one or the other, don't pass both.

If it turns out that success could represent partial success, indicate that separately. Failure is usually the bail-out option.

I've worked with developers that only ever handle the success case and in many scenarios just implementing a success callback would suffice in this case. A multi-state callback would be catastrophic option for that style of programming as they'd assume success.